# Finagle client handle onConnected event

Tags: scala, asynchronous, finagle

I'm trying to build async client for some tcp service. Service requires handshake. When initial connection is established I can make handshake, but if connection fails and finagle reconnects i have no way to make handshake again. Is there a way to catch connected event?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the method [prepareConnFactory](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/Codec.scala#L40) in your codec.
Basically each time finagle establishes a connection it will execute this method before putting the connection into the queue.

We use this feature in the [ThriftClientFramedCodec](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-thrift/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/thrift/ThriftClientFramedCodec.scala#L76) to verify that the server is compatible with our custom thrift protocol.